# What does "sidespin" mean as a verb?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, ambiguity

"What do you think is the best way to get back on track for those that have found themselves side spun?"

It's a question about game strategies. I guess the user seems to mean 'get bogged down' by 'side spun'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To side spin = to have one's attention distracted from the main aim by a peripheral issue. I have only seen it used in the passive.

OED:

> **sidespin**  n. **Sport spinning motion given to a ball around its horizontal axis.**
>
> 1887   Boy's Own Paper 3 Sept. 778/3   The round-arm service..puts a slight side-spin on the ball.
>
> 2001   Golf Mag. Feb. 70/2   Focus on rhythm and balance to reduce sidespin and hit straighter shots.

The 2001 quote shows that the effect of sidespin is to take the projectile away from its intended, straight or direct course.

Comment: The 1887 quote shows that the effect of sidespin is to gain an advantage by making the return more difficult.